# unable to getChildByTag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm following along with the Lynda.com iOS tutorial for game development which uses cocos2d (version 2). The instructor uses the following code to make the sprite image increase in size upon a touch event. The log statement in the code below is working (i.e. touch events are enabled) but the image is not getting larger when I click on the simulator.  It turns out that mole in this line is nil

```
CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1];
```

Here's the whole method

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location ];
    CCLOG(@"touch happened at x: %0.2f y: %0.2f",location.x, location.y );
    CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([mole boundingBox], location)) {
        [mole runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                         [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.1],
                         [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.0],
                         nil]];
    }
}
```

The mole is appearing on the screen with this `init` method below. I'm assuming the line from above `CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1];` is supposed to get a reference to the mole as a child but it's not obviously working.

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *mole = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mole.png"];
        mole.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);
        [self addChild:mole];
        mole.tag = 1;

        CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
        bg.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:bg z:-1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can you tell from the above code why mole here is nil?

```
 CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1];
```

Update

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#import "cocos2d.h"

// HelloWorldLayer
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
}

// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - HelloWorldLayer

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        // create and initialize a Label
//      CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
//
//      // ask director for the window size
//      CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
//
//      // position the label on the center of the screen
//      label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
//      
//      // add the label as a child to this Layer
//      [self addChild: label];

        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"moles.plist"];
        CCSprite *mole = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"a0010.png"];
//      CCSprite *mole = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mole.png"];
        mole.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);
        mole.scale = .25;
        //between 0 255
//        mole.opacity = 100;
        NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%04i.png",i];
            [frames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:frameName]];
        }
        CCAnimation *a = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:1.0f/24.0f];
        [mole runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:a restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        [self addChild: mole];


        CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
        //supposed to fill whole screen but not

        //got next three lines from SO
    //stackoverflow.com/questions/12383228/how-to-set-background-image-for-the-entire-scene-in-cocos2d-xcode
        CGSize imageSize = bg.contentSize;
        bg.scaleX = s.width/ imageSize.width;
        bg.scaleY = s.height/ imageSize.height;

        bg.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:bg z:-1];
        //
        // Leaderboards and Achievements
        // *

//      // Default font size will be 28 points.
//      [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:28];
//      
//      // to avoid a retain-cycle with the menuitem and blocks
//      __block id copy_self = self;
//      
//      // Achievement Menu Item using blocks
//      CCMenuItem *itemAchievement = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Achievements" block:^(id sender) {
//          
//          
//          GKAchievementViewController *achivementViewController = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
//          achivementViewController.achievementDelegate = copy_self;
//          
//          AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//          
//          [[app navController] presentModalViewController:achivementViewController animated:YES];
//          
//          [achivementViewController release];
//      }];
//      
//      // Leaderboard Menu Item using blocks
//      CCMenuItem *itemLeaderboard = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Leaderboard" block:^(id sender) {
//          
//          
//          GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
//          leaderboardViewController.leaderboardDelegate = copy_self;
//          
//          AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//          
//          [[app navController] presentModalViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES];
//          
//          [leaderboardViewController release];
//      }];
//
//      
//      CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemAchievement, itemLeaderboard, nil];
//      
//      [menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:20];
//      [menu setPosition:ccp( size.width/2, size.height/2 - 50)];
//      
//      // Add the menu to the layer
//      [self addChild:menu];

    }
    return self;
}

//- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
//{
//    acceleration.x
//}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location ];
    CCLOG(@"touch happened at x: %0.2f y: %0.2f",location.x, location.y );
    CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1 ];
    NSLog(@"mole %@", mole);
//    if (CGRectContainsPoint([mole boundingBox], location))
//    {
//        [mole runAction: [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.1]];
//        
//    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([mole boundingBox], location)) {
        [mole runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                         [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.1],
                         [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.0],
                         nil]];
    }
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark GameKit delegate

-(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you checked you `mole`? Is it nil ? Also the animation you are giving is very less prominent. Change scale `1.1` to `2.0`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes, thanks, mole is `nil`, but I don't know why. Just copied the code from the tutorial. The mole is on the screen. Do you see a problem with this line `CCSprite *mole =  (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:1];`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I changed the title and body of the question to reflect fact that mole is nil

Comment: The code here seems to be OK from first sight. Would you mind posting your whole project?

Comment: I've had problems in the past setting tags to '1' because other views that I hadn't explicitly tagged, also had the tag '1'.  Would you mind changing it to something like 14562 and see if it still has a problem?

Comment: @Logan tried it, doesn't fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @TiborUdvari I posted a lot more code. The code I didn't post is just boilerplate cocos2d from the rootviewcontroller and game config

Comment: in your updated code(HelloWorldLayer.m), it doesn't appear that you are setting the tag on the mole sprite, so your getChildByTag will not return a sprite. As a side note; unless you are going to be dynamically changing the tag later, I would set up a `#define kMoleSprite 1234` or similar and use that to tag and later reference the sprite tag. Also, just for debugging, I would substitute the `getChildByTag` call with your own loop just to inspect the current tags of the children of the current node.

Comment: Are you running this with ARC?  Is it possible that your object is being released from memory?

Comment: Yep in your new code you forgot to set the tag. Anyhow please consider using Cocos2d v3 for your future projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  // set the tag value mole sprite in init method (HelloWorldLayer.m).

   CCSprite *mole = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"a0010.png"];
    //      CCSprite *mole = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mole.png"];
    mole.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);
    mole.scale = .25;
    mole.tag=1;
```

Comment: OP just to clarify in the HelloWorldLayer.m code you've posted you are not actually setting the tag

Answer (score 0):

```
to check null value:

    if(mole!=NULL) //check null value
   {
      if (CGRectContainsPoint([mole boundingBox], location)) 
        {
          [mole stopAllActions];
          [mole runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                     [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.1],
                     [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:1.0],
                     nil]];
         }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do what KARTHIK RA says.

Alternatively, you can subclass CCSprite and add the touch detection and handlers within the subclass.  I do this when I have several touchable sprites because:

- It eliminates the needs to continually check all the children in a scene/layer on touch
- You can create the action ahead of time within your sprite class and just run it when the touch is detected
- It separates the action logic from the scene
- When touch is detected, you know for a fact which object is touched

Good luck with cocos2d.  It's a great engine.  If you do migrate to version 3, keep in mind that "tag" is no longer a property of CCNode.  It has been replaced by "name" which is actually a string type.  Tag was an int type.